# Cannot specify where clause in main query when use full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to sum Allowance Monthly Allowance and OT Allowance calculate per Period

When I specify where clause in Main query result in sub-query will not appear

[image]

[image]

This is my script

```
select isnull(T1.Emp_Id,T2.Emp_Id) Emp_Id,isnull(T1.Track,T2.Track) DayTY
   ,isnull(Pay,0) MealAllowance_Mont, isnull(MealAllowance,0) MealAllowance
   ,isnull(Pay,0) + isnull(MealAllowance,0) Tot, isnull(t1.Period,T2.Period) Period
from [dbo].[SPCM_TX_MonthlyAllowance] T1
full outer join
(
   select T2.Emp_Id, T2.Track,T2.Period,sum(MealAllowance_OT) MealAllowance
   from [dbo].[SPCM_Cal_OTLog] T2
    where LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, T2.Period,23),7) = '2019-11'    
   group by T2.Emp_Id,T2.Track,T2.Period
) T2
   on T1.Emp_Id = T2.Emp_Id   
   order by Period desc
```

My problem is I can not specify Period both table

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You don't ask a question, or state why what you have isn't working as you expect. You mention a `WHERE` in the "main" query but there isn't one in your SQL. Also, why are you converting a Date and Time column to a `varchar` in the subquery's `WHERE`, and that `varchar` doesn't have a length declared. You should be using proper date logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `union all` and `group by`.  I can't quite figure out what you want for the result set, but something like this:

```
select t.Emp_Id, t.Track, t.period,
       sum(pay), sum(MealAllowance_OT), sum(MealAllowance)
from ((select empid, track, period, Pay, MealAllowance_OT, MealAllowance
       from [dbo].[SPCM_TX_MonthlyAllowance] T1
      ) union all
      (select Emp_Id, Track, Period, 0, MealAllowance_OT, MealAllowance
       from [dbo].[SPCM_Cal_OTLog]
      )
     ) t
where period >= '2019-11-01' and
      period < '2019-12-01'
group by t.Emp_Id, t.Track, t.period
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon the explanation in your answer pointed me in the right direction. Yes i explain in question post not clear because i need more to join 3 table. Actually i don't clear about difference normal join T1 and subquery join such as left join(select * from ....)